# ACF fields on WooCommerce Product not displaying

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, woocommerce-theming

I am customizing an old theme called AmazeTheme which was not specifically made with WooCommerce support. And an `woocommerce.php` was at theme's root. However with help of plugins like **Simply Show Hooks** and **Show current template** I am able to see where to put which info.

But I am having an weird problem. The ACF fields I have added are not visible at all. I even tried to assign the field group inside product loop section.

I also tried the following method.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'view_acf_field_for_single_product', 10 );

function view_acf_field_for_single_product(){  
  if (function_exists('the_field')){
    the_field('shop_support');
  }

}
```

And inside the loop of single-product.php

```
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); 
                   $dump = get_fields();
            ?>
        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

And then did `var_dump($dump)` at desired place of the file.

This site's php version is 5.6.40 and WooCommerce version is 3.4.8
WP version is 4.9.18

I have looked up many solutions. Also tried the WooCommerce Hooks but still no clue why ACF not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some weird reasons, this approach worked for me (`path/to/theme/woocommerce/single-product.php`):

```
<?php if (get_field_objects()): 
     foreach ( get_field_objects() as $field_id => $field ) : 
      $value = trim($field['value']); 
         if (!empty($value)) : 
?>
            <div class="product_field" id="field-<?php echo $field_id; ?>">
                <?php the_field($field_id); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; // end of the loop. ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also the following one for Category (`path/to/theme/woocommerce/archive-product.php`) pages:

```
<?php
$extra_info = get_field_object( 'category_details', get_queried_object() );
if ( !empty($extra_info) ) :
?>
    <div class="category_field" id="field-<?php echo $extra_info['key']; ?>">
        <?php echo $extra_info['value']; ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Even at these locations, `get_fields()` did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'view_acf_field_for_single_product', 10 );

function view_acf_field_for_single_product(){  
  global $post;
  if (function_exists('the_field')){
    the_field('shop_support', $post->ID);
  }

}
```

Not tested.

Comment: Following your suggestion I tried by, grabbing the get_the_id() into a variable inside loop and then outside the loop I dumped the `get_fields($ID_of_the_product)`. Still no luck.

Comment: And also modified that function as shown by you. No luck either.